# Window background turns gray when showing javascript alert message

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I m using some serverside validation and if any problem comes I m showing a pop up message using javascript using

```
  page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock
```

but when my message is displayed the background of the window turns gray.

can any one help me to get rid of this gray window

```
       public static class Alert
{

/// <summary>
/// Shows a client-side JavaScript alert in the browser.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="message">The message to appear in the alert.</param>
public static void Show(string message)
{
    // Cleans the message to allow single quotation marks
    string cleanMessage = message.Replace("'", "\\'");
    string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + cleanMessage + "');</script>";

    // Gets the executing web page
    Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

    // Checks if the handler is a Page and that the script isn't allready on the Page
    if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert"))
    {
        page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Alert), "alert", script);
    }
}
```

}

I am using this Function

Comment: That code has nothing at all, directly, to do with displaying an alert. What is your *real* code?

Comment: I have pasted the code as well

Comment: What browser are you using? Are you also using any javascript scripts that *might* override the `alert` function? Typically this could be a jQuery modal plugin of sorts....

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using the Javascript alert() function, you have absolutely no control over how the browser handles it. Each browser looks slightly different. However, you can expect that it will be a modal popup with your content, and a single "Ok" button. Beyond that, you have no control.

If you want something different, you'll have to use more complex javascript; perhaps using a jQuery plugin to display your message exactly how you want, or overriding the alert() function.